# What kind of exception is raised by ActiveRecord::lock!?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, exception, locking

I am using lock! in my code and want to catch the exception thrown if lock! fails for some reason (e.g. cannot get the lock). What kind of exceptions can lock! throw? I checked the ruby docs but couldn't find the specific Exception classes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the source for that [locking call](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/locking/pessimistic.rb). It calls reload and its source looks like this:

```
          # File lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2333
2333:       def reload(options = nil)
2334:         clear_aggregation_cache
2335:         clear_association_cache
2336:         @attributes.update(self.class.find(self.id, options).instance_variable_get('@attributes'))
2337:         @attributes_cache = {}
2338:         self
2339:       end
```

so when you call reload(:lock => lock) as the call to lock does it it really updating the attributes of that record.

There are a lot of different situations here. You could try to lock a record that dosnt exist, or lock one that has been locked elsewhere. What error are you interested in catching?

Comment: The errors when the record doesn't exist and if the record has been locked elsewhere. What are the names of the corresponding exceptions so I can restrict my rescue statement accordingly?

Comment: Good question, I believe you want to catch `RecordNotFound` and `StaleObjectError`. All the errors that AR will raise can be found at: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/errors.rb

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, probe.

Consider the following pair of functions:

```
def long_hold
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    u = User.find(220)
    u.lock!
    sleep 100.seconds
    u.email="foo@bar.com"
    u.save!
  end
end

def short_hold
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    u = User.find(220)
    u.lock!
    u.email="foo@bar.com"
    u.save!
  end
end
```

In my setup (OSX 10.11, ruby 2.2.4, rails 4.2, postgres 9.5), running `long_hold` in one rails console and then running `short_hold` in a second console, I observe `short_hold` blocks until `long_hold` completes; moreover, instrumenting the code with puts, we see that while `long_hold` is sleeping, `short_hold` is waiting to acquire the lock.

Assuming no caveats about the independence of rails consoles, this suggests that no exceptions are thrown if a second process tries to lock a row that is already locked, but that process blocks until the first completes.